# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

i have this two models:

```
class Opcion extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'opciones';

    public function pregunta(){ 
        return $this->belongsTo('Send\Pregunta', 'pregunta_id');
    }
}

class Pregunta extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'preguntas';

    public function opciones(){ 
        return $this->hasMany('Send\Opcion', 'pregunta_id');
    }
}
```

then in my controller:

```
 class GraficosController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(){
        $preguntas= \Send\Pregunta::where('encuesta_id','=',1)->get();
        $opciones= $preguntas->opciones();


        return view('graficos.grafico')->with(['preguntas'=>$preguntas,'opciones'=>$opciones]);
    }
}
```

im getting this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::opciones(), im trying to get all the "opciones" related with  "preguntas"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because the `get()` method returns a `Collection` object, which you can think of as an array of results. So the first element returned by your query would be  `$preguntas[0]`, and you could do this:

```php
$opciones= $preguntas[0]->opciones();
```

But if you know that you're only going to get one result from your query, then you should use the `first()` method instead of `get()`. [`first()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) will return an instance of the first result from your query.

```php
$preguntas= \Send\Pregunta::where('encuesta_id','=',1)->first();
$opciones= $preguntas->opciones(); // Now this will work
```